# How to set the controller and model in layout/default to load in all pages

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Layout**

For all pages when I load the data works but the model and controller do not work. Other model which I have assigned works. I mean, one controller and model of layout for all pages but other page their own model and controller. One controller for all pages and one for each page.

```
<?php foreach ($sidebars as $row):  ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $row->title; ?> </td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div id="main" role="main" class="content">
            {content}------here this show my pages content other model and controller
</div>
```

**Controller**

on my controller i load my page

now if i load other page again i have to enter the

```
$this->load->model('side_model');
            $data['sidebars'] = $this->side_model->get_sidebar();
```

this one of my page controller it works but other controller if don't mention about so not works i want to make it as controller for every page and i don't want to mention in each page controller above code

```
"<?php"
    public $layout = 'default'

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('side_model');
        $data['sidebars'] = $this->side_model->get_sidebar();   
        $this->load->view('Layout/default',$data);
    }
```

**Model**

```
function get_sidebar(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('side');
    $this->db->where('active','1');
    $this->db->order_by('added_date', 'DESC');

    return $this->db->get()->result();
```

How do I make one main controller and model with many function for all pages?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called core/MY_Controller.php:

```
    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model("side_model");
            $this->data["sidebars"] = $this->side_model->get_sidebar();
        }

        protected function get_html_meta($meta){
            // method will be available for all extending controllers
            return ucfirst($meta)." ".date("Y-m-d");
        }

    }
```

From now on you should extend MY_Controller and not CI_Controller, in your existing controller you can now pass the varible `$this->data` which is available to the view (i have added a few examples of `$this->data` usage and its scope:

```
class your_controller extends MY_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->data["html_meta"] = $this->get_html_meta("this is meta");
        $this->data["html_title"] = "Hello World!";
        $this->load->view('Layout/default',$this->data);
    }

}
```

**NOTE:** unlike `$this->data`, the scope for `$data` is inside the function you declare it only.

As for a global model, once the MY_Controller constructor (or autoload.php) loads the model you can invoke the model as long as you other controllers extend MY_Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Write you own controller

```
class ParentController extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}

class Blog extends ParentController {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not explain anything. Literally.

Comment: it works but when i load other controller it doesn't work how can i make a controller to load in pages whitout mentioning in each controller when my each controller has it own view and model

Comment: It will help you use parent controller all function.

Comment: @rafiq you have to extend all you child controller with parent controller instead of CI_Controller.

Comment: actuly i have create a : layout/default...this default is on my all pages not i want to set a controller in default so it will load along with other controller and model